# Are there any pros to add root module in build.sbt?

Tags: sbt, multi-module

I have multi module sbt project:

```
├── build.sbt
├── bar
│   ├── build.sbt
│   └── ...
├── foo
│   ├── build.sbt
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

And 2 versions of `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val foo = project in(file("./foo"))
lazy val bar = project in(file("./bar"))
```

And second version:

```
lazy val foo = project in(file("./foo"))
lazy val bar = project in(file("./bar"))

lazy val root = Project(id = "root",
  base = file(".")) aggregate(foo, bar)
```

What are the differences between these versions? Are there any pros in second version?

Comment: I presume the two versions are just for the top-level build.sbt, and the question can be answered without reference to them.

Answer (score 0):

With your second version loaded type `projects` at the sbt command line and you should see that you have three of them. The one with a star at the front is the default project. It will be your `root` project. Commands that you type will apply to it. As it is an aggregate project the commands will be applying in turn to both `foo` and `bar`.

`package` is a good example command - typing it should produce a jar file that has both the `foo` and `bar` classes in it, if that is what you want.